# Creating growth series in R

Tags: r

Consider the Loblolly dataset in the MASS package.

```
head(Loblolly)
    height age Seed
1    4.51   3  301
15  10.89   5  301
29  28.72  10  301
43  41.74  15  301
57  52.70  20  301
71  60.92  25  301
```

For each seed I would like to create new variables height1, age1 and height2,age 2. The output would be something like...

```
height1 age1 height2 age2 Seed
4.51      3    10.89    5  301
10.89     5    28.72   10  301
28.72    10    41.74   15  301
```

Forgive me if this has been asked before but I have been searching around and cannot find anything similar.

Comment: Try `Loblolly %>% group_by(Seed) %>% transmute(height1 = height, age1 = age, height2 = c(tail(height,-1),NA), age2 = c(tail(age,-1),NA)) %>% ungroup` with the `dplyr` package.

Comment: This works. It creates a final observation for every seed that includes NAs but that can be easily removed.

Comment: `Loblolly %>% group_by(Seed) %>% transmute(height1 = height, age1 = age, height2 = c(tail(height,-1),NA), age2 = c(tail(age,-1),NA)) %>% dplyr::filter(!is.na(age2)) %>% ungroup()` should take out the rows with `NAs`.

Comment: yeah perfect... I had forgotten about "tail"

Comment: I am glad that was useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```
# get data frame length
n <- dim(Loblolly)[1]

df <- NULL

# combine appropriate vectors
df$height1 <- Loblolly$height[1:(n-1)]
df$age1    <- Loblolly$age[1:(n-1)]
df$height2 <- Loblolly$height[2:n]
df$age2    <- Loblolly$age[2:n]
df$Seed    <- Loblolly$Seed[1:(n-1)]

# flatten list as data.frame
head(data.frame(df))
```

Comment: Yeah, it's the right idea. However, with this code the last observation of one seed is paired with the first observation of the next seed. But maybe with a group_by statement in dplyr this would work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method that will give the "lead" of each observation by Seed.

```
myList <- split(Loblolly, Loblolly$Seed)
myList <- lapply(myList, function(x) setNames(cbind(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1)),
                                   paste0(names(Loblolly), rep(1:2, each=length(Loblolly)))))

dfNew <- do.call("rbind", myList)
```

A sample of the returned data is

```
head(dfNew, 10)
       height1 age1 Seed1 height2 age2 Seed2
329.13    3.93    3   329    9.34    5   329
329.27    9.34    5   329   26.08   10   329
329.41   26.08   10   329   37.79   15   329
329.55   37.79   15   329   48.31   20   329
329.69   48.31   20   329   56.43   25   329
327.12    4.12    3   327    9.92    5   327
327.26    9.92    5   327   26.54   10   327
327.40   26.54   10   327   37.82   15   327
327.54   37.82   15   327   48.43   20   327
327.68   48.43   20   327   56.81   25   327
```